# How do I read a CSV file into an HTML table using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, erb

I am trying to read a simple CSV file into an HTML table to be displayed in a browser, but I'm running into trouble. This is what I'm trying:

Controller:

```
def show
  @csv = CSV.open("file.csv", :headers => true)
end
```

View:

```
<% @csv.read %>
<% @csv.headers.each do |head| %>
<%= head %>
<% end %>

<table border="1">
  <% @csv.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <% row.each do |element| %>
      <td> <%= element %> </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Output:

```
Name Start Date End Date Quantity Postal Code
```

Basically I am only getting the header, and the CSV body isn't being read and rendered.

Comment: What gem are you using for CSV reading? Evidently, your `@csv.each do...` loop may not be correct. But it's difficult to analyze your problem without knowing what `CSV` is designed to do.

Comment: I was using the Ruby 2.0.0 standard CSV Library API

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ended up being the final solution:

Controller:

```
  def show
    # Open a CSV file, and then read it into a CSV::Table object for data manipulation
    @csv_table = CSV.open("file.csv", :headers => true).read
  end
```

View:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
  <% @csv_table.headers.each do |header| %>
    <th><%= header %></th>
  <% end %> 
  </tr>
  <% @csv_table.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
    <% row.each do |element| %>
      <td><%= element[1] %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

Reading the CSV into a table was the correct way to go about it, but when iterating through the rows, I had to specify `element[1]`, since `element` is actually an array of `[header, element]`.

Comment: Since the variable `row` is a hash, you could also do `each_value` to get each element instead (a little bit neater).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the same but didn't need to use the ".read"

```
  def show
    # Open a CSV file, and then read it into a CSV::Table object for data manipulation
    @csv_table = CSV.open("file.csv", :headers => true)
  end
```

and using the key/value for the elements.

```
<% @csv_table.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
    <% row.each do |key, value| %>
      <td><%= value %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```